# Simple post request with DHC

Tags: php, post, dhc

I have a page with just :

```
<?php
  echo "OK";
  var_dump($_POST);
```

I try to send POST request with DHC, but it's like no data received in my page ...:
[image: dhc request]

Comment: Change the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Thanks !And if I want to send json data and display it, how can I do?

Comment: The set the contetnt type to application/json and read it with `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Thanks and how can I use my variable in my script?
I send json data with ajax request, how can I do something like :   $idProd = $_POST['product_id'];